# Why is Math.max and Math.min not able to be added or subtracted to?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to figure out why the Math.max and Math.min aren't working.
I know I could use and if else statment if I wanted too, but is there a way to do it without if else?

```
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter three integers(Use enter in between): ");
    int x = Scan.nextInt();
    int y = Scan.nextInt();
    int z = Scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(
      Math.min(x, Math.min(x, z))+", " // Prints the minimum of {x, z}
      +Math.max(x, Math.max(y, z))+", " // Prints the maximum of {x, y, z}
      +(
        Math.max(x, Math.max(y, z)) // Get the max of {x, y, z}
        +Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z)) // Get the min of {x, y, z}
        // Sum should be the sum of smallest and largest of {x, y, z}
      ) // Convert to string
      +(-x-y-z) // The sum of -1 * x+y+z, converted to String
    ); // println
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "aren't working".

Comment: I guarantee to you that `Math.max` and `Math.min` are working. What output are you getting and how does it differ from what you expect it to be doing?

Comment: This part is useless `Math.min(x, Math.min(x, z))` : if `z` is the min, then it doesn't matter to do min a second time with `x`. If `x` is the min, then you are just doing `min(x,x)`.

Comment: if you need the same thing twice (min/max of x, y and z), use a variable. will probably help clean this up.

Comment: Why do you have a '+' sign at the end AND at the start of the lines?

Comment: I've broken down your statement into its component parts. Hope this helps. Depending on your goal, it looks like there's a lot potentially wrong with it. Probably what you want is to change `Math.min(x, z)` to `Math.min(y, z)` and also surround the `(Math.min() + Math.max()) + (-x-y-z)` part with parentheses.

Comment: If any of variables used with `+` operator is a `String` then `+` will work like String concatenation.
So if you have `System.out.println(1 + "," + 2 + 3);` it will result into `1,23` not in `1,5`. To get `1,5` you need to use brackets like this `System.out.println(1 + "," + (2 + 3))`

Comment: `Math.min(x, Math.min(x, z)) `
i guess you want to have `Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z))`

Answer (score 1):

Once change `Math.min(x, Math.min(x, z))` to  `Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z))`, seems ok to me 
[Example online](https://ideone.com/sb8YKU)